# Make visible page only in the trash

Tags: plugin-development, functions

i'm working on a plugin that generate some pages and they are hidden to User in the wp admin. But i had not choise to do a radical action and hidden ALL pages created from my plugin. The ideal for me is hidden the pages from WP admin in "pages" but make them visible in "Trash". I make this function to hide pages:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'mic_hide_pages_in_wp_admin' );
function mic_hide_pages_in_wp_admin($query) {
    global $pagenow,$post_type,$post_status;
    $result = mic_get_all_id();
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type =='page') {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = $result;
    } 
}
```

mic_get_all_id() is my function that get all ID of generated pages for hide them. Now, how can i make visible all this page when some of them are put in the trash?

Comment: This sounds like a strange solution to implement, you realise WordPress will permanently delete those  posts after 30 days? Have you tried asking abut your original problem?

Comment: I make this answer caus i image the situation if the user make a mistake to delete a page. If all the pages are not visible, how  can he recover it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you're worried a user might delete a page your plugin creates, why not ask how to prevent the deletion being possible? Or how to create the URLs without having pages in the database that can be deleted? There are lots of options here!